# How to properly document class' static variables?

Tags: python, coding-style, documentation, code-documentation

What is the preferred way to document static variables in classes?

```
class Foo(object):
    """
    Foo doc.
    """

    bar = 'bar'
    """
    Bar doc.
    """


class Foo(object):
    """
    Foo doc.
    """

    # Bar doc.
    bar = 'bar'
```

Something else...?

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to associate docstrings with variables. The [PEP](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0224/) to add attribute docstrings failed.

The best way for code documentation is probably a comment rather than a docstring, so that you aren't introducing ambiguity of the kinds that the PEP discusses. You can additionally document them in the class' docstring if you want them in `help()` and docs.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use the Google-style DocString format and my approach to static attributes is to include them in the class' DocString.

E.g.

```
class Bicycle:
    """
    A class defining a Bicycle

    Attributes:
        NUM_WHEELS (int): The number of wheels that a bicycle has: 2.
    """
    NUM_WHEELS = 2
```

This is definitely an opinionated topic though. Depending on how visible you want your attributes to be, it might also make sense to just document them using a normal comment above the attribute's definition. E.g.

```
class Bicycle:
    """
    A class defining a Bicycle
    """
    # The number of wheels that a bicycle has
    NUM_WHEELS = 2
```

Comment: I guess with google-style, both static and non-static attributes are listed under `Attributes:` then?

Comment: Class/static variables are documented here in the class. Instance/non-static variables would be documented in the \_\_init__ method's DocString.

Answer (score 0):

The [Epydoc](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/) documentation tool does provide support for variable doc strings:

http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/manual-docstring.html#variable-docstrings

The format is just as you have suggested above:

> if a variable assignment statement is immediately followed by a bare string literal, then that assignment is treated as a docstring for that variable